# How to find the start and end position of a page when using column css style?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

In our mobile website, we use column style to show the article, user can swipe left or right to read the content.

For some reason, we have to identify the start point and end point of given page and insert a span to that particular position for late use.
As the following image shows, the red arrows point at where we want to insert the span.
The position is different on each devices, so we have to calculate it when user load the page.

[image]

We have done some researches but found nothing.
We totally have no clues about how to do it.
Please help us, Thank you very much.

Comment: If that is possible, I believe it would be very complicated. Does this span really need to be in the text or can it be positioned absolutely close to the text?